# Gwan report.c statistics

Tags: performancecounter, g-wan, usage-statistics

I am testing on G-wan server performance and it's very amazing!!! Here is the output from report.c

> Requests
> All: 5,725 (6.06% of Cache misses)
> HTTP: 66 (1.15% of all requests)
> Errors: 70 (1.22% of all requests)
> CSP: 5,650 (98.69% of all requests) Exceptions: 1
>
> Connections
> Accepted: 4,717 (1.21 requests per connection)
> Closed: 4,372
> Timeouts: 682 (14.46%) Accept:682   Read:0   Slow:0   Build:0   Send:0   Close:0
> Busy: 345 (Waiting: 334 Reading: 9 Replying: 2 Sending: 0 Pushing: 0 Relaying: 0 Closing: 0)

I found that the Errors rate seem to be quite high, and there an exceptions occur on CSP too, could anyone tell me what did "Errors" mean and how to avoid it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the "Errors" rate seem to be quite high

That's `HTTP errors` (wrong requests coming from a client, not found resources, etc. - look at the `error.log` file for a trace).

The only way to avoid HTTP errors is to prevent clients from connecting to the server.

If you can't live with this "high rate of HTTP errors" of *1.22% of all requests* then use a G-WAN connection handler (with the `HTTP_ERROR` notification) to make G-WAN ignore HTTP errors and close the connection without sending an HTTP error message (just return 0; in the handler) - but that's probably not what most users want.

> there an exceptions occur on CSP too

An exception means a 'graceful crash report' was issued for a servlet bug. As you have only 1 crash on 5,650 dynamic requests, that was probably during the servlet development. Look at your `error.log` and `trace` files to check what happened.

Note that the "cache misses" statistics are for static contents only (1.15% of all your HTTP requests).

Apparently, not all your clients are responding in the timely fashion: you have timeouts and pending requests.

Comment: Thank you for your information! Beside, I have another problem of G-wan, it will become unstable on everyday 00:00 and finally got a message on gwan.log `[Mon, 19 Aug 2013 00:07:13 GMT] * child died 3 times within 3 seconds` , is it a bug?

Comment: I think this problem cause by hyperisor, I will try to test Gwan again on dedicate machine!

Comment: That new problem for 4-years old code that worked fine so far is a platform issue, for which we have found a workaround, to be published with the next release in a few weeks.